# Join one xml file nodes python

Tags: python, xml

I have XML file like:

```
<root>
    <scen name="n1">
        <case name="c1">
           <res>Text1</res>
        </case>
    </scen>
    <scen name="n2">
        <case name="c234">
           <res>Text</res>
        </case>
    </scen>
    <scen name="n1">
        <case name="c2">
           <res>Text1</res>
        </case>
        <case name="c1">
           <res>Text2</res>
        </case>
    </scen>
</root>
```

And i would like to parse it and make something like that:

```
<root>
    <scen name="n1">
        <case name="c1">
           <res>Text1</res>
           <res>Text2</res>
        </case>
        <case name="c2">
           <res>Text1</res>
        </case>
    </scen>
    <scen name="n2">
        <case name="c234">
           <res>Text</res>
        </case>
    </scen>
</root>
```

I preferred python, but I just cant solve it. I tried many options but none of them worked. Maybe any suggestion ?

```
def join(root):
    index = defaultdict(list)
    for scenario in root.findall(".//scenario"):
        index[scenario.get('name')].append(scenario.getchildren())
    nRoot = ET.Element('root')
    elems = []
    for i in index:
        scen = ET.Element('scenario',name=i)
        for elem in index[i]:
        for e in elem:
            scen.append(e)
        elems.append(scen)
    nRoot.extend(elems)
    return nRoot
```

Data set is big ( root have about 1500 nodes) but i quess after this method i duplicate some of nodes. And still case nodes are not merged.

Comment: *I tried many options*. Can you add some of them? and tell us that what's your problem exactly with them?

Comment: I added my own method

Answer (score 0):

You are not taking care of the case where the `case` names are also same, it does not get automatically handled by `sceno.extend(s.getchildren())` . Try this code instead -

```
def join(root):
    nRoot = ET.Element(root.tag)
    for n in root:
        path = ".//scenario[@name='%s']" % n.attrib['name']
        scens = root.findall(path)
        if not scens:
            sceno = ET.SubElement(nRoot, 'scenario',names=n)
            sceno.extend(n.getchildren())
        else:
            sceno = scens[0]
            for c in n:
                cases = sceno.findall(".//case[@name='%s']"%c.attrib['name'])
                if cases:
                    sceno.extend(cases[0].getchildren())
                else:
                    sceno.append(c)
            sceno.extend(n.getchildren())
    return nRoot
```

Comment: u forget about  right bracket in `cases = sceno.findall(".//case[@name='%s']"%c.attrib['name']`